# nodejsでの逐次処理について

Tags: javascript, node.js

nodejs の逐次処理について質問です。

- JavaScript Promiseの本
  https://azu.github.io/promises-book/

上記サイトを参考に、コールバック地獄を回避するために、以下のようなタスク１～３の逐次処理するロジック（タスクの処理結果を次のタスクに渡す）を記載し、希望通りタスク１～３が逐次実行されるのは確認できました。
ですが、js 初心者のため、以下の疑問が出てきましたので質問させていただきました。
（抽象的な質問で申し訳ありません。。。）

(1) このやり方が一般的なのでしょうか？
(2) このやり方での問題点は何かありますでしょうか？
とりあえず動作確認のみ行いました。が、このロジックが正しいかどうかの判断がついていません。

```
// 何かしらの非同期処理
// この関数では入力パラメータの value に +1 するだけ
// 入力パラメータの error は reject を発生させて、catch() が動作しているか確認用
function async_task(value,error) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      if (error === undefined){
        resolve(value+1);
      }
      else {
        reject(error);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

// var promise = async_task(1,'task1 error'); // 処理1(エラー発生させる場合)
var promise = async_task(1); // 処理1
promise.then( (result) => {
  console.log(`task1 end: result:${result}`);
  return async_task(result); // 処理2
}).then( (result) => {
  console.log(`task2 end: result:${result}`);
  return async_task(result); // 処理3
}).catch( (error) => {
  // どっかでエラーが発生した
  console.log(error);
}).then( (result) => {
  // 最後のまとめ処理
  console.log('complete');
});
```

以上、宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise のロジックに関しては全く問題がないと思います
質問者様が考えるように、Promiseを使った記述はなんでもできる代わりに、冗長になりがちです
この問題を解決するために async / await という機能が追加されました

async function は戻り値を Promise に強制してくれます

```
console.info( (async function() {return 10;})() ) // Promise {status: "resolved", result: 10}
console.info( (async function() {return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));})() ) // Promise {status: "pending"}
```

await は async function の中にのみ記述できます
await someValue someValue を Promise に強制し、resolved になり次第、後続の処理を実行します

```
(async function() {
  // 1
  await 'hello';
  // 3
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  // 4
})();
// 2
```

promise の reject には throw が対応し、
promise の catch には try ... catch が対応します

async / await を使って記述してみると、以下のようになると思います

```
{
const waitFor = async (ms) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
const fakeAjax = async (value, error) => {
  await waitFor(1000);
  if (error) {
    throw new Error('fakeAjax error');
  } else {
    return value + 1;
  }
}

const task1 = async (arg) => {
  console.log(`task1 start`);
  return await fakeAjax(arg/*, 'task1_error' */);
};
const task2 = async (arg) => {
  console.log(`task2 start`);
  return await fakeAjax(arg);
};
try {
  const initialValue = 1;
  const task1Result = await task1(initialValue);
  console.log(`task1 end: result:${task1Result}`);
  const task2Result = await task2(task1Result);
  console.log(`task2 end: result:${task2Result}`);
} catch (e) {
  console.info(e);
}
console.info('complete');
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
こんな便利なやり方があるんですね。もっとjsの仕様を理解してからコードを書くべきでした。。。。
アホな質問をして申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: async / await を使いこなすには Promise をマスターするのが大切なので、今回の練習で動作を確認されたのはとても大切な知識になったと思います
Promise の知識なしでは async / await を使いこなすことはできません